# App to block or limit my network operator?

Tags: mobile-network

I'm having some trouble with my network operator. They have recently changed the underlying network they used by default to a different one and the service is very poor now. I have come to realize that they still support (and will keep on supporting, I've checked this) the old network, it's just that my phone won't use that one by default but the new one.

Anyone knows if there's an app to limit the network operator my phone uses, or to block the one that doesn't barely work?

This is for both calls and Internet.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Please [edit](https://android.stackexchange.com/posts/197433/edit) your question to include phone make/model as well as which carrier you are using. Also mention if you tried altering the APN and what happened when you did.

Comment: What do you mean by "underlying network"? Did they change the band steering so your device is using a different band by default? Are we talking about LTE, HSPA, CDMA, etc. or something else? Your question is very vague...